# Spring Data Redis - StreamMessageListenerContainer only spawning one thread

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I am using spring data redis to subscribe to the 'task' redis stream to process tasks.
For some reason redis stream consumer only spawns one thread and processes one message at a time sequentially even thought I explicitly provide a Threadpool TaskExecutor.

I expect it to delegate the creation of threads to the provided Threadpool and spawn a thread up to the Threadpool configured limits. I can see that it is using the give TaskExecutor, but it's not spawning more than one thread.

Even when I don't specify my own taskExecutor, and it internally defaults to SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor, the problem still **continues**. Tasks are processed sequentially one at a time, one after the other, even when they are long lasting task.

What am I missing here?

```
@Bean
public Subscription
      redisTaskStreamListenerContainer(
      RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
      @Qualifier("task") RedisTemplate<String, Task<TransportEnvelope>> redisTemplate,
      @Qualifier("task") StreamListener<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> listener,
      @Qualifier("task") Executor taskListenerExecutor) {

 
    StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>>
        containerOptions = StreamMessageListenerContainerOptions.builder()
        .pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(consumerPollTimeOutInMilli))
          .batchSize(consumerReadBatchSize)
          .executor(taskListenerExecutor)
          .build();

    StreamMessageListenerContainer<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> container =
        StreamMessageListenerContainer.create(connectionFactory, containerOptions);

    StreamMessageListenerContainer.ConsumerStreamReadRequest<String> readOptions
        =
        StreamMessageListenerContainer.StreamReadRequest
            .builder(StreamOffset.create(streamName, ReadOffset.lastConsumed()))
            //turn off auto shutdown of stream consumer if an error occurs.
            .cancelOnError((ex) -> false)
            .consumer(Consumer.from(groupId, consumerId))
            .build();


    Subscription subscription = container.register(readOptions, listener);
    container.start();
    return subscription;
  }


  @Bean
  @Qualifier("task")
  public Executor redisListenerThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(30);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("redis-listener-");
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
  }
```

Comment: have you figured out what was the problem?

Comment: @NunoNelas I ended up calling container.register() more than once with the same lister class. I am uncertain if thats the recommended approach, but it works.  Example :

 `List<Subscription> subscriptions = IntStream.range(0, taskQueueProperties.getConsumer().getConcurrency()).mapToObj(i -> container.register(readOptions, listener)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: thank you! don't know if it helps, but I also ended up creating an `ExecutorService` inside my consumer and call it on `onMessage` method